# How turn off External Display, on closing lid in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, suspend, laptop, lid

I believe that there are a lot of questions asking the other way around. However for me, on closing my laptop's lid the external monitor is still running which I would like it to stop continuing to run,when I close my laptop lid.

Ubuntu Version: 20.04.1

I did the following things, However none of them seem to work:

1. Edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to the following:

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

2. Changed the `lid-close-ac-action` option in dconf-editor under `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power` to `suspend`


   **EDIT:**
3. Changed the `lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor` option in dconf-editor to `true`.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need three configurations:

- in `dconf-editor` `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` the setting `lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor` enabled
- in file `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` change the parameter `IgnoreLid` to `true` (ending up with `IgnoreLid=true`)
- in file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` you need `HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an additional setting.
Depending on what you are running, on the command line try:

`gsettings set com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor true`

or

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor true`

or both, if you're not sure...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However I changed the setting using  `dconf`, rebooted and No change has been observed.

Comment: @PKMAN630 you need to change 3 parameters, the `dconf` one, on `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` and `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`